# Table rows not filling full length

Tags: html, html-table

I am using a Bootstrap table design and I have 8 header cells and 5 body cells, but for some reason the rows are only stretching across 4 columns. I am not sure why and have hit a blank.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">B2C2</th>
      <th scope="col">Kraken</th>
      <th scope="col">CEX</th>
      <th scope="col">Qredo</th>
      <th scope="col">Gemini</th>
      <th scope="col">Coinbase</th>
      <th scope="col">Galaxy</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">BTC</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">ETH</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">ADA</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">DAT</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">TEST</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This currently looks like this:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi add `<td></td>` tag 4 more time. check this code. It will help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>**strong text**
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">B2C2</th>
      <th scope="col">Kraken</th>
      <th scope="col">CEX</th>
      <th scope="col">Qredo</th>
      <th scope="col">Gemini</th>
      <th scope="col">Coinbase</th>
      <th scope="col">Galaxy</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">BTC</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">ETH</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">ADA</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">DAT</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">TEST</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>**strong text**
</table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Realised what I was doing wrong, so to make the rows go across all the columns I needed to add the same amount of td tags to how many theads I had, for example I had 3 td's and needed to add 4 more.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">B2C2</th>
      <th scope="col">Kraken</th>
      <th scope="col">CEX</th>
      <th scope="col">Qredo</th>
      <th scope="col">Gemini</th>
      <th scope="col">Coinbase</th>
      <th scope="col">Galaxy</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">BTC</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">ETH</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">ADA</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">DAT</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">TEST</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Or `<td colspan="7"></td>`.